# Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL with Dropbox API

Tags: java, dropbox-api

I'm tryin to use the Dropbox API for a project and when I create the connection the error 400 spawns in my console.

the code is:

```
String url = "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/get_metadata";
    
    try {
        
        
        HttpURLConnection openConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        //if(url.contains(" "))
            //url = url.replace(" ", "%20");
        openConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        openConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization",
                "Bearer <REDACTED>");
        openConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        openConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        openConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        String jsonBody = "{\r\n" + "    \"path\": \"\",\r\n" + "    \"recursive\": true,\r\n"
                + "    \"include_media_info\": true,\r\n" + "    \"include_deleted\": false,\r\n"
                + "    \"include_has_explicit_shared_members\": false,\r\n"
                + "    \"include_mounted_folders\": true,\r\n" + "    \"include_non_downloadable_files\": true\r\n"
                + "}";
        
        try (OutputStream os = openConnection.getOutputStream()) {
            byte[] input = jsonBody.getBytes("utf-8");
            os.write(input, 0, input.length);
        }
```

I searched on old topics the solution to add the IF cycle to replace the space inside the url but didnt work. So any advice ??

Comment: By the way, it might be easier to use this API by using `HttpClient` (added in Java 11), then the experience is not as low level...

Comment: Can't you compare your request with a working one by using Fiddler (or another debug proxy)?

Comment: I m following a guide that my Professor give to me and he used this code, the connection btw works with Spring

Comment: What's in the response body? It should contain a more useful error message. By the way, you should [revoke](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#auth-token-revoke) that access token since you posted it publicly.